# Is there an option in gvimdiff that can copy all the differences in an output file?

Tags: vim

Ex: file1 contents =

```
abcde
pqrst
xyz
```

file2 contents=

```
abcde
xyz
lmnop
```

If we give the command `gvimdiff file1 file2`
out file contents=

```
pqrst,
,lmnop
```

Comment: Your question and the provided samples don't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option – `gvimdiff` is for viewing and editing; the *out file contents* expected by you can be produced by adapting the output of `diff`:

```
diff file[12]|sed 's/^< \(.*\)/\1,/;s/^> /,/;t;d'
```